# Why do I get undefined?

Tags: javascript

Will someone answer a small question for me that I simply do not understand; why is it that the output of this function is undefined? I expected to get "cheese whiz". A plain answer would be immensely helpful to me towards understanding JS basics.

```
var x = "cheese ";
var y = "whiz";

function cheeseWhiz (x,y){
  console.log (x+y);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't show how you call the function. But no matter how I think about it, the function wouldn't log `undefined`. Can you explain what you mean by "the output of the function is undefined"?

Comment: I find it quite funny (and frustrating) that this question receives so many answers that are all based on speculation.

Comment: ...and so many upvotes!

Comment: Amazingly, the only correct answer so far is the deleted one with 3 downvotes ;)

Comment: @georg Yes, that was the only correct answer, but the user could have had the trouble of writing more than 5 words.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: I'm not saying it's good, but it's correct, unlike others.

Comment: @georg: that answer might be correct but not necessarily answering the op's question.

Comment: @aaron: please don't just add code to the question.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm using repl.it. When I ran the function, it gave back undefined. The myriad of answers that came through helped immensely though.

Comment: @FelixKling, Yeah sorry about that.  I relaized after the fact I was making an assumption on what the OP was doing.  Thank you for correcting it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include how you called the function and provide a copy of the complete output. Take a screenshot if you have to.

Comment: So you are in fact not calling the function.

Comment: @FelixKling Apparently, being a newcomer, I don't have the required amount of points to add an image to my post. If you use https://repl.it/languages/javascript and copy my exact code into the editor, and hit run, it will output undefined on the righthand side.

Comment: I already fixed that for you :)

Comment: Best " fun question " on SO! Great stress buster indeed!

Answer (score 5):

Because you need to call the function.

```js
var x = "cheese ";
var y = "whiz";

function cheeseWhiz (x, y) {
  console.log (x+y);
}

cheeseWhiz(x, y);
```

Also, you *are* <s>likely</s> running the code in the console which prints the result of the last expression/statement. Because the last expression was a function declaration, no result was returned, therefore the console yields undefined.

@[Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) added the missing piece to this answer.

> calling cheeseWhiz(x, y); will also "output" undefined because the function doesn't return anything and the console prints the value of the last expression/statement.

Comment: Where would an `undefined` come from if the function were never called?

Comment: OK, I edited my answer after OP clarified his question.

Comment: and he reverted it back...;-)

Comment: @leo: It was not the OP who added the additional code.

Comment: Now the question was clarified. You were correct :)

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that calling `cheeseWhiz(x, y);` will also  "output" `undefined` because the function doesn't return anything and the console prints the value of the last expression/statement.

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling this function and wondering why are you getting `undefined` back is because it actually doesn't `return` anything, it just `console.log`s.

```
var x = "cheese ";
var y = "whiz";

function cheeseWhiz (x,y){
  return x+y;
}
console.log(cheeseWiz(x,y));
```

Comment: What makes you think this is what the op is doing?

Comment: That he says he's getting undefined? as it's just the return value of his function, regardless of how he calls it

Comment: They say "the output of the function is undefined". That could mean what you think or might mean something else. Fact is that there is no way to know for sure without knowing how they call the function or how the code is executed.

Comment: @felix-kling yes, the question is a bit ambiguous. I understand the "output" of a method the value that it returns, not what it logs.

Comment: As it turns out, the OP wasn't calling their function at all ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the function. Try this :

```
var x = "cheese ";
var y = "whiz";

function cheeseWhiz (x,y){
  console.log (x+y);
}
cheeseWhiz(x,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call function it will not call by itself like `cheeseWhiz (x,y);`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting `undefined` is because you're defining a function, but you don't call it actually.

Change to:

```js
function cheeseWhiz (x, y){
    console.log (x + y);
}

cheeseWhiz("cheese ", "whiz");
```

Comment: How does not calling the function make the function "output undefined"?

Answer (score 0):

the x & y arguments in your cheezeWhiz function create locally scoped variables.

```
var x = "cheese ";
var y = "whiz";

function cheeseWhiz (x,y){ //creates new x,y variables in local scope
   console.log (x+y);
 }
 function cheeseWhiz2 (){ 
   console.log (x+y); //will move to outer scope to find x & y variables
 }

 cheezeWhiz(x,y) // this passes in the outer x & y. will log 'cheezewhiz'
 cheezeWhiz('peanut','butter') // this will log 'peanutbutter'
 cheezeWhiz2() // gets outer x & y. will log 'cheezewhiz'
 cheezeWhiz2('peanut','butter') // also gets outer x & y. will log 'cheezewhiz'
```

here's a good run down on JavaScript Scope http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

OP is using [REPL.IT](https://repl.it/languages/javascript), and it looks like it always outputs what gets returned by the *last* function call if they don't redirect that function output to a variable

#### Example 1:

[image: Hello World]

#### Example 2:

[image: World]

So even though I am calling a function three times, the console on the right shows the output from the last function that doesn't have its output saved.

In OP's case, they never actually call their function, so it shows `undefined` as the last return value from the last function call (aka, from nothing).

Even if they did run `cheeseWhiz`, they'd see the `console.log` value, but they'd still see a return value of `undefined`.

#### Example 3:

[image: Cheese Whiz]

So to answer the original question, assuming that "output" means "return value," the return value of the `cheeseWhiz` function is `undefined` because it never returns anything!

If you'd like it to return something, so that you can use the value later on, you'd want to use a `return` statement, rather than just outputting the string to the console.

```
var x = "cheese ";
var y = "whiz";

function cheeseWhiz(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}

var result = cheeseWhiz(x, y);

// Do whatever you want with `result`, like output to the console
console.log(result);
```